# How to access the html contents in the php code segment within the same php file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a php file with html contents and php contents.

```
<body>
    <a href="settings.php" onclick="edit_enable()">
        Edit section
    </a>

    <div class="container" hidden name="Edit">
        <section class="ac-container">
            <p>This is the Edit Section</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

and I have a php segment that contains the function edit_enable()

```
<?php
    function edit_enable() {
    }
?>
```

I want this function to be able to access the  named 'Edit' and change the visibility along with other properties within.

//UPDATE
I simply added an example as such, my main intention is to access/change the html content, all using the php code.

Comment: in simply terms you can't call a php function the way your proposing. You have placed a php function name where a javascript function is suggested.

Comment: *access the named 'Edit'* what does that mean?

Comment: @Dagon he means be able to access the div which he has placed a name `Edit`. Hackman all this should be done with Javascript

Comment: this can be done withoud php , only using javascript

Comment: Put php logic before the template, so you can manipulate the style in time.

Comment: Do you understand the various technologies that you are utilising. The `onclick="edit_enable()"` is Javascript (client bit). The `function edit_enable()` is the web server bit (PHP). Need I say more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss-used some of the html attributes as well. You have taken some form attribute values and placed them inside a `<div`. This is not supported.

I have rewritten your html, placing the `hidden` in a meaningful `style` attribute. and renamed the `Name` attribute to the widely used `id` attribute. Then i placed a javascript function to toggle the display of the `div`

```
<body>
<a href="settings.php" onclick="edit_enable();">
    Edit section
</a>

<div class="container" style="display:none;" id="Edit">
    <section class="ac-container">
        <p>This is the Edit Section</p>
    </section>
</div>

<script>
    function edit_enable() {
        var div = document.getElementById('Edit');
        div.style.display = (div.style.display == 'block') ? '' : 'block';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I just gave a very generic example.
My question was to check if at all i could change/access the properties/content of already existing html code within the same php page, all inside a php code segment.